# Ruelle's Theorem

Tags: reference-request, operator-theory, ergodic-theory

When reading the spectral theorem of Ruelle's operator, a crucial question arises: Is there an effective method to compute the leading eigenvalue and the equilibrium state explicitly?

Let's consider a circle map $T: S^1\to S^1$ with a Markov partition and a smooth function $\tau: S^1 \to \mathbb{C}$. Ruelle's operator is defined as follows:
$$L_{\tau}f(x)=\sum_{Ty=x}e^{\tau (y)}f(y)$$

Under standard assumptions, $L_{\tau}$ possesses a leading eigenvalue $\exp\left(\sup\{{h_{\mu}(T)+\int \tau d\mu: \mu \text{ is invariant}}\}\right)$. Therefore, the question is how to explicitly find, express, or calculate the entropy $h_{\mu}(T)$ and the equilibrium state $\mu$ that achieves the supremum.

Any references on this topic would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to MathOverflow! Could you replace the wording "Under standard assumptions" with an explicit list of the assumption that you are imposing? This will improve the accessibility of your question to a wider audience and decrease the risk of confusion (for many results, which assumptions are considered "standard" depends a lot on personal interpretation and on the sources from which one has learnt the result).